# Is there a way of checking if an action has been successfully completed in ThingSpeak?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read data in ThingSpeak, but I would like to have some conditional statement that says if the data was not read successfully, then a certain error message should display. Is there a way to check if a specific Read action was successful, so that I can do this?

Comment: Can you say more about what kind of read actions your using?  ThingSpeak is just running MATLAB code, so you have access to all the same handling for outputs.  If you're using the standard functions, or using a webhook, etc...  We need to know more about the kind of read you're doing in order to guide you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a built-in operation with the ThingSpeak Arduino Library: `ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus()`

Here's some code to get the last status and test it:

```
// Check the status of the read operation to see if it was successful
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if(statusCode == 200){
    Serial.println("Counter: " + String(count));
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Problem reading channel. HTTP error code " + String(statusCode)); 
  }
```